Replace median line with mean in box plot (ggplot2)
I know how to add a mean line on top of a box plot with stat_summary, but I would like to remove the median line altogether and just have the mean show in the box plot instead.
Minimal example:
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="errorbar", 
               mapping = aes(ymin = ..y.., ymax = ..y..),
               width = 0.75, color = "red", size = 1)


Does this answer your question?

Just to make sure, the question is framed correctly: You want the quartiles and the strange whisker-and-outlier rules but the 50 % quantile is the one to be dropped and replaced by the mean? It does not feel right.

@JoshAllen, Thanks, I believe that answers my question.

This is a sure way to confuse your audience..
